# Add objects with specific category to join table and then display on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm building a RoR app where Users can click book categories to add lists of books to their profile. I'm a bit new to this stuff, and I am currently a little stuck as to where to go next.

Models:

1. User (from Devise)
2. Book
3. Book_List (join table)

I have a few thousand books with various categories. Upon clicking a category, I want the books of that category to be added to the User's profile page.

This is what I have so far:

**book.rb**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_lists
  has_many :users, :through => :book_lists
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :book_lists
  has_many :books, :through => :book_lists

end
```

**book_list.rb**

```
class BookList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**devise_create_users.rb Migration**

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
    # i only included relevant to the question stuff here. 
    # Standard Devise stuff taken out.
      t.integer :user_id
```

**book Migration**

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :category
      t.string :title
      t.integer :book_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**book_list Migration**

```
class CreateBookLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :book_lists do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**book_list_controller.rb**

```
class BookListController < ApplicationController
  def save_book
    @saved_book = BookList.new(params[:saved_book]
    @saved_book.user = current_user
    @saved_book.save
  end
end
```

**book list view**

```
<%= form_for BookList.new, :url => "/books/save_book" do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :book_id, :value => @book_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Save Books" %>
<% end %>
```

What should I be adding to get the books to save to the User's profile page based on book category?

Sorry if the above code is nonsensical in any way. I pieced it together from various forums.

EDIT:

```
CodeApp::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'}
  get "profile", to: "profile#show"

  resources :books
  root "books#welcome"
  get "search", to: "search#index"
  get "about", to: "books#about"
  get "books", to: "books#index"
  post "save_book", to: "book_list#save_book"
```

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
<%= form_for BookList.new, :url => "/books/save_book" do |f| %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_for @saved_book, :url => "/books/save_book" do |f| %>
```

Comment: Ok, I changed that, but now I get `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

Comment: @someonesomewhere Can i see your routes ?